# "await is only valid in async function" discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm writing this code and I'm getting a "await is only valid in async function" on the line with an arrow below. I've done a bit of searching around but I'm not entirely sure what's wrong.

```
       if (message.attachments.first()) {
        console.log("cool file.")
        if (verifyFile(message.attachments.first())) {
            console.log("epic file!!")
   --->     await request.get(message.attachments.first().url).then(async (data) => {
                fs.writeFileSync(`${directory}/${message.author.id}_unobfuscated.lua`, data)
                var options = {
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'url': 'https://obfuscator.aztupscripts.xyz/Obfuscate',
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
```

Comment: You...need to put this in an asynchronous function. Either `async function` (async normal functionor `async () =>` (async arrow function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your function you are currently asynchronous. You can do it by using one of these options below. (depending on your function type)

Arrow function: 
`async (parameters) => {}`

Normal function:
`async function(parameters){}`

Hope i could help!

Answer (score 0):

To use `await` the statement which uses `await` needs to be directly in the body of an `async` function.

For example:

This works

```
const getValue = async () => 5

const myFunction = async () => {
   let val = await getValue()
   console.log(val)
}
```

This doesn't

```
const getValue = async () => 5

const myFunction = () => {
   let val = await getValue()
   console.log(val)
}
```

In your case:

```
let myFunc = async () => {
     ...othercode
    if (message.attachments.first()) {
        console.log("cool file.")
        if (verifyFile(message.attachments.first())) {
            console.log("epic file!!")
   --->     await request.get(message.attachments.first().url).then(async (data) => {
                fs.writeFileSync(`${directory}/${message.author.id}_unobfuscated.lua`, data)
                var options = {
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'url': 'https://obfuscator.aztupscripts.xyz/Obfuscate',
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
    ...othercode
}
```